# boost::variant and operator<< overloading

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, ostream, boost-variant

I wanted to test a simple thing like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template<typename T1,typename T2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T1,T2>& dt){
    os << dt.first << dt.second;
    return os;
}



int main(){

   boost::variant<int, std::pair<int,int>, bool> v;
   v = std::pair<int,int>(3,3);
   std::cout << v << std::endl;

}
```

This should actually work, because for normal types, like `int, double` and so on, it compiles.
`boost::variant` has a printer vistor which it uses internally to output the content to the stream.
Actually this fails to compile, but I do not really know the problem:

The codes fails here: in variant_io.hpp

```
template <typename OStream>
class printer
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
private: // representation

    OStream& out_;

public: // structors

    explicit printer(OStream& out)
        : out_( out )
    {
    }

public: // visitor interface

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(const T& operand) const
    {
        out_ << operand;  // HEEEEEEERRRRREE!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }

private:
    printer& operator=(const printer&);

};
```

**With the message:**

```
/usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp|64|error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

**Does someone know what I did wrong, and why?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not the place we need to know to be able to diagnose the problem. When there is a problem with template definition, the compiler prints a chain of expansion. We need that complete output to tell you what's going on.

Comment: Since the error messages seem to be from MSC++, I'll mention that you need to take the messages from the "Output" tab in Visual Studio, the "Errors" windows has the notes filtered out and is useless for the purpose. The notes immediately follow the error message.

Comment: think...think...think... the answer is actually pretty easy this time around. That's no excuse for sloppy question though; whenever asking about problems compiling something, _complete_ compiler output is _mandatory_.

Comment: sorry for the dump question: I added the solution to the problem above, as also mentioned in the other posts below

Comment: @Gabriel Please do not edit your question to let others know that the issue is resolved. Mark an answer as accepted instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely it's not finding your overload of `operator <<`, and then gets confused trying to match some other overload, leading to whatever message you're getting.

What you did wrong: You overloaded the stream operator in the global namespace instead of the namespace the right-hand-side class is defined in, so it's not found by ADL.

Trying to overload the stream operator for a standard class is a doomed exercise in the first place, unfortunately. You can't actually do that. I'm not sure if there is an explicit rule against it. However, if you place the operator in namespace `std` as you have to in order to make it properly findable by ADL, you violate the rule that you can't add your own stuff to namespace `std` except in very specific cases, this not being one of them.

The bottom line is that `std::pair` doesn't have a stream operator, and it's not possible to legally add a generic one that is useful. You can add one for a specific instantiation, if one of the parameters is a class you defined yourself; in this case the operator needs to be placed next to your own class.

Comment: There is a rule saying that you must not put anything in the `std` namespace except overloading it's symbols for _user-defined types_.

Answer (score 4):

Overloaded `operator<<` must be findable by argument dependent lookup. That means you have to put it in associated namespace of one of the arguments.

The first argument has only one associated namespace, `std`. The second also has only one associated namespace, `std`. However it is only permitted to overload symbols in `std` for user-defined types. Since `std::pair<int, int>` is *not* user-defined type, **this is not allowed**. However it **is** allowed for a structure or class you define yourself. Obviously in that case it is easier to place the overload to your namespace, not `std`.

That said if you put that overload in namespace `std`, it *will* actually work.

Also note, that `boost::tuple` does have `operator<<` (in separate header that you have to include, but it does), so you can use that instead.